# What is the best way to calculate the fit of the mixture distribution to the actual data?

Tags: distributions, goodness-of-fit, fitting, gaussian-mixture-distribution, mixture-distribution

I have fitted the mixture of Gaussians to the natural log of the data. I know that the model is not a very good fit to the data in the tail region, however in the high density region the actual data seems to follow Lognormal.

What is the best way to check whether the model is a good fit in the high density regions?